# Random name ( RUBY ) PLEASE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Have the function Cus_free_makers_eg1heChallenge(str) take the name parameter being passed to return "Hello Cristina!" if the name parameter is equal to "Cristina", return "Hello Kay!" if the name parameter is equal to "Kay" or "Hello there!" if the name parameter is equal to any other.

```
def Cus_free_makers_eg1heChallenge(str) 
  return str 
end # keep this function call here 
puts Cus_free_makers_eg1heChallenge(STDIN.gets)
```

Comment: What's the specific issue?

Comment: Please share the code you already wrote.

Comment: def Cus_free_makers_eg1heChallenge(str)


  return str

end

# keep this function call here 
puts Cus_free_makers_eg1heChallenge(STDIN.gets)

Comment: I don't know how to get the code to return the desired outputs. I'm very new to coding but thanks for looking

Comment: I've moved your comment into the post and formatted it as code; code is almost always  impossible to read in comments. You need to check the value of `str` and see if it matches the strings in question. If it does, return the appropriate string; if it doesn't, return the other string. Which part(s) are the problem?

Comment: Thanks for that Dave. I managed it eventually, turns out I only had to use IF statements Doh

Comment: https://replit.com/@num8er/Cusfreemakerseg1heChallenge

Comment: Something like `"Hello #{%(Christina Kay).member?(str) ? str : 'there'}"`?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a bit off-topic, but first off, you should probably keep the method name shorter and simpler - probably not more than one or two words. Otherwise, when you call the method, it's a mouthful to type. The name should also describe what the method does, so the code is more readable.

Here is how I would write the method:

```
def hello(name)
    if name == "Cristina" or name == "Kay"
        return "Hello #{name}!"
    end
    "Hello there!"
end
```

Comment: For boolean expressions, you should use `||` instead of `or` (which is for control-flow).